# grails withTransaction - why is it on a domain object?

Tags: grails, rollback

We need to be able to rollback a complex transaction in a service, without throwing an exception to the caller.  My understanding is that the only way to achieve this is to use withTransaction.

The question is:

1. why do I have to call this on a domain object, such as Books.withTransaction
2. What if there is no relevant domain object, what is the consequence of picking a random one?

Below is more or less what I am trying to do.  The use case is for withdrawing from an account and putting it onto a credit card.  If the transfer fails, we want to rollback the transaction, but not the payment record log, which must be committed in a separate transaction (using RequiresNew).  In any case, the service method must return a complex object, not an exception.

someService.groovy

```
Class SomeService {
    @NotTransactional
    SomeComplexObject someMethod() {
        SomeDomainObject.withTransaction{ status ->
            DomainObject ob1 = new DomainObject.save()
            LogDomainObject ob2 = insertAndCommitLogInNewTransaction()
            SomeComplexObject ob3 = someAction()
            if (!ob3.worked) {
                 status.setRollbackOnly() // only rollback ob1, not ob2!
            }
            return ob3
        }
    }
}
```

The above is flawed - I assume "return ob3" wont return ob3 from the method, as its in a closure. Not sure how to communicate from inside a closure to outside it.

Comment: Why not add the `@Transactional` annotation to a method?

Comment: @christopher, I believe creating a transaction outside of the one created with "withTransaction" would serve no purpose other than to reduce performance (marginally).  we understand we have to use withTranaction to be able to rollback without throwing an exception.

Comment: I meant instead of! I see. There is specific scope for the use of the `withTransaction` method, and yeah that's one of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To your primary question: you can pick a random domain object if you want, it won't do any harm.  Or, if you prefer, you can find the current session and open a transaction on that instead:

```
grailsApplication.sessionFactory.currentSession.withTransaction { /* Do the things */ }
```

Stylistically I don't have a preference here.  Others might.

> Not sure how to communicate from inside a closure to outside it.

In general this could be hard; `withTransaction` could in principle return anything it wants, no matter what its closure argument returns.  But it turns out that `withTransaction` returns the value returned by its closure.  Here, watch:

```
groovy> println(MyDomainObject.withTransaction { 2 + 2 })
4
```

By convention, all `withFoo` methods which take a closure should work this way, precisely so that you can do the thing you're trying to do.

Comment: Nice!  one question, how did you run groovy console which picked up the grails withTransaction and domain object stuff?  To test such features I usually resort to creating a new grails project in Intellij, which takes some time.

Comment: @JohnLittle `grails shell` and `grails console`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this question was from a grails 2 application and this problem from 2015 has been fixed before now.

I can't find this in any of the grails 2 documentation, but services have a magic `transactionStatus` variable injected into their methods. (at least in grails 2.3.11)

You can just leave all the annotations off and use that injected variable.

```
Class SomeService {
    SomeComplexObject someMethod() {
        DomainObject ob1 = new DomainObject.save()
        LogDomainObject ob2 = insertAndCommitLogInNewTransaction()
        SomeComplexObject ob3 = someAction()
        if (!ob3.worked) {
             transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly() // transactionStatus is magically injected.
        }
        return ob3
    }
}
```

This feature is in grails 2, but not documented.  It is documented in grails 3.
https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/services.html#declarativeTransactions

search for `transactionStatus`.